# Azure b2c profile edit policy custom UI

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to customize the UI experience for the profile edit policy on Azure B2C. I am able to add a custom html page to my profile edit policy and I can see that custom html is properly displayed when user tries to edit profile.

> Issue:
>   When profile edit policy is triggered, user is redirected to login screen which is currently default provided by Azure, is there a way to customize this login ui also.

Comment: It doesn't look like we have the same level of control.  In a sign-in policy, there is no option to provide a custom html page.  Under user & groups -> company branding there are some basic options though.

Comment: Have you configured **Sign-up or sign-in policies** ? As I consider, the page was redirected to Azure default page  when users need to login. So try to set the policies of **Sign-up or sign-in** and test again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [company branding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding) for the login screen. That's the same customization as sign-in page as mentioned in the Note on the [AAD B2C User interface customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) documentation.